# How to control the isArray value from the calling function? (modify $resource params)

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I was wondering how can I set the `isArray` parameter in the `resource`, because sometimes I want it to be `true` and sometimes `false`

Here is my resource factory code

```
dummyServices.factory('Dummy', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://dummyServer/dummyApp/dummyREST/:methodName', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                isArray: false // <-- isArray: someParameter ???
            }
        });
    }]);
```

I use it like this:

```
$scope.myDummyObj = Dummy.query(
        {
            methodName: 'dummyMethod'
        },
        myDummyArgument
    );
```

How can I set `isArray` from my `Dummy.query` call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you might already know, $resource never intended to be a replacement for a more powerful $http service, and, as such, the authors simply didn't bother exposing a more powerful and configurable API.

That said, the only way to configure the resource on run-time is to wrap it in it's own custom factory. But that just makes things uglier, IMO.

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2JhCbXWpz8pMmEObPYVg?p=preview)</kbd>

```
app.factory('Dummy', [
  '$resource',
  function ($resource) {

    return function(config){

      return $resource('http://dummyServer/dummyApp/dummyREST/:methodName', {}, {
        query: angular.extend({
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          isArray: false // <-- isArray: someParameter ???
        }, config)
      });

    };

  }
]);
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myDummyObj = Dummy({isArray: true, method: 'GET'})
                      .query({methodName: 'dummyMethod'});
```

Comment: Thanks, nice `extend` approach

Comment: Nyc approach but y use all this ? query default is suppossed to return array of objects. SHouldnt the use of a custom action be better?